# "smooth like butter in daily life" is right?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I want to express melting naturally or smoothly like butter in everyday life.
How do you like it? Can I write "smooth life butter in daily"?

Comment: I the title you have "smooth like butter in daily life",  and in the body you have "smooth life butter in daily".  Which phrase are you asking about?

Comment: What is "smooth like butter".  Is this a metaphor like "The installation of the software was smooth like butter", or "My daily life is smooth like butter"?

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I wanted to choose a brand slogan that means it naturally melts into everyday life. It's a figurative expression, but I want to use the phrase "It melts naturally like butter in everyday life."

Comment: "It naturally melts" ... What is "it"

Comment: @haley, if you provide additional information, please edit your question to add the information, rather than just adding a comment.

Comment: It's nearly always *smooth **as** [something stereotypically smooth]*, not ***like***. But actually, it's [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smooth+like+butter%2Csmooth+as+butter%2Csmooth+as+silk%2Csmooth+like+silk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmooth%20like%20butter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmooth%20as%20butter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmooth%20as%20silk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmooth%20like%20silk%3B%2Cc0) to be *as smooth as **silk*** rather than ***butter***.

Answer (score 2):

Normally we say "**as** smooth **as**" rather than "smooth **like**". I don't understand what you are trying to add with "in daily life".

I would go for this:

> melting as smoothly as butter.

Comment: How, though, does butter melt smoothly? I can imagine butter, not melted when applied, but melted by the relevant friction, being a lubricant, and, indeed, there are plenty of homely examples one can imagine.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you have obviously never made gingerbread. "First, melt the butter..."

Comment: But it, er, just melts, like, ice, wax or palm oil, yes, smoothly (i.e. not in a series of jumps). Everything melts smoothly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey noooo! It's a goldilocks situation: water and wax aren't viscous enough, plastic is too viscous... and metals actually melt very fast when you get to the right temperature. Melting butter is viscous, silky... excuse me, I think I'll go and make some gingerbread....